# Fixing Lat Long Asynchroneous Function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I know there are a lot of threads on here about Asynchronous functions in javascript, but I cant figure out how to use:

```
var lat = 0;
var address = '10 maple way';
function getLat(address){
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat());
          } 
        });
    }
```

to get the latitude into my lat varibable. Can someone please show me how to write the callback, pass the callback, and use the callback to get the latitude into my lat variable?

Thanks

Comment: It _is_ putting the latitude in the `lat` variable. Or at least I assume so - I am not familiar with the API you use. At any rate, it seems like that's what your code is doing. Are you trying to use `lat` before `getLat` populates it?

Comment: Did you check if results[0] points to the data you are looking for?
I mean, geocode will execute the callback, and will put results[0].geometry.location.lat() in the "lat" variable, im not familiar with the API, but maybe it is no entering the if... did you check if the code inside the if (status === google....) is at least executed? I may be a problem with the status not being OK.

Comment: that's not even valid javascript, you have an extra `)` in there

Comment: the problem you are having is not getting the value into lat, it's how you are using lat to begin with. A callback wont help if the rest of your code is outside the callback, expecting `lat` to be set synchronously